# blank pdf file issue in node js

Tags: node.js, express, pdf

Hi everybody I am facing an issue where when I create and save pdf contents to a pdf file it always opens up blank here is  my code snippet
i am using express.js

`````
fs.writeFile(
      "response.pdf",
      pdfData.data,
      { encoding: "utf-8" },
      function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("File is created successfully.");
      }
    ); ```


here is an example of the pdf data I'm trying to add to the pdf
```%PDF-1.5
%����
3 0 obj
<</ColorSpace/DeviceRGB/Subtype/Image/Height 224/Filter/F...(more characters)````

please advice
`````

Comment: If you want to generate pdf using node js, my suggestion is please use pdf-kit npm package.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfkit

Comment: Thank you for the reply I have tried but it struggles with adding the pdf data I get as a response from another server. is there no alternative method to solve this problem please ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have removed the encoding feature and the pdf still comes out blank.

Comment: Thank you for the reply .Once I have saved it to bin file how do I convert it to a viewable pdf file ?

Comment: finally managed to solve the issue using  Blob package